# Vuetify table not scrolling in ie11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Im using Vuetify in my Vue project and I have not been able to make it work in ie11..
I want to when content is not available to make it responsive, or to add scroll horizontal scroll bar on ie11, when content is too wide.

```
[Codepen Link][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/kematzy/pen/gKVwwe
```

Comment: You've added link to empty pen (first save pen, then copy link). Your question should also contain relevant code

Comment: ok , sorry edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that I had, display: flex on my app container, when I changed it to display: block, it started working in IE :)

Answer (score 1):

You can head over to the documentation landing page 
and read about E11 & Safari 9 support

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start